# Java 3D out of bounds

Tags: java

I am having problems accessing the values inside the 3d array. Sometimes it givese correct values but sometimes it gives me random nos. that does not exist inside the array.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[][] strData = {{"0022", "Mercado, Jennylyn"},
                              {"0324", "Collins, Max"},
                              {"0044", "Torres, Andrea"},
                              {"3365", "Pinto, Sam"},
                              {"5463", "Zamora, Gwen"}};

        int[] intEmpNo = {0022, 0324, 0044, 3365, 5463};

        double[][][] dblData = {{{0324, 20000},
                                 {3365, 50000}, 
                                 {0022, 30000}, 
                                 {0044, 27000}},

                                {{3365, 15200},
                                 {0022,  7800},
                                 {0324,  9350}},

                                {{3365,  8000},
                                 {0044, 12300}}};

        int intShit = 4;

        for(int intLoop = 0; intLoop < 5; intLoop++, intShit--){
            System.out.print(strData[intLoop][0] + " " + strData[intLoop][1] + " ");
            System.out.print(dblData[0][2][0] + "\n" );
        }
    }
```

Comment: specify what incorrect values and other output

Comment: I tried accessing dblData[0][2][0], it outputs 18.0.

Comment: ``int intShit = 4;`` - are you honest??

Comment: This is only a scratch. Didn't notice that it was still there. Sorry. Hehehe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java if you put 0's in front of numbers they are treated as *OCTAL* numbers by the compiler (base-8). 0022 is 22 in base-8 and 18 in base-10. This is then cast to a double and stored as 18.0.

Comment: Ooh. That explains it. Thanks a lot, Sir. :)

Comment: Prefixing numbers with a zero is a common mistake. I see this as a design flaw, but read more about that on [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/221797/reasoning-behind-the-syntax-of-octal-notation-in-java)